# JavaScript Regex Explanation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below regex to validate against any html tags in a text area, 
If someone enters any html tags into the textarea I have to show validation message,

Regex used :

```
/<(\w+)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/
```

Could someone explain the above regex,
I am validating it against any html tags in a text area,
It works for all the cases but the below CASE is not validated,

`</p>` is getting passed through without any client validation
I don't want users to even enter a closing HTML tag

Comment: Well, it basically attempts to match an opening tag.

Comment: What should I edit for the regex to not accept even the CLOSING TAGS

Comment: Are you just trying to restrict the < and > characters? The answer you have accepted will return a match on sentences like "if 1 < 2 then 55 > 10"

Comment: Do not forget to filter input/output on server side too. If you store and than show this data on the page, such kind of filtering only with JS won't be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try -

Regx to restrict html tags -

```
/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i
```

or

```
/<(.|\n)*?>/g
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f2S6R/8/)

Answer (score 3):

I would perform this kind of validation like so:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = 'whatever </p>';

if (d.getElementsByTagName('*').length) {
    alert("You have typed some HTML");
}
```

Comment: </p> was just an example....my regex allows all the CLOSING HTML TAGS.....I dont want to allow even if the string contains just the CLOSING HTML TAGS

Comment: this is a pretty neat idea, it still fails on sentences that contain the < and > chars in the wrong order. not sure there's much he can do about that though

Comment: @magritte Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: hey jack, sure - i put it in a comment on the question but e.g. "if 1 < 2 then 55 > 10", you could imagine they might be typing something in the box that involves maths calculations in a sentence.